# Stata string to date/time conversion error

Tags: string, date, time, stata

I'm trying to convert a string variable into Stata date format and am getting an odd error - Stata seems to be rounding to an arbitrary second.

Here is my code:

```
gen start_time=clock(v8, "YMDhms")
format start_time %tc
```

[This is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQBGL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
gen double start_time = clock(v8, "YMDhms")
```

From `help datetime`:

> Warning: To prevent loss of precision, datetime SIFs must be stored as
>   doubles.